# Are shared objects/DLLs loaded by different processes into different areas of memory?

Tags: c++, dll, shared-libraries

I'm trying to figure out how an operating system handles multiple unrelated processes loading the same DLL/shared library. The OSes I'm concerned with are Linux and Windows, but to a lesser extent Mac as well. I presume the answers to my questions will be identical for all operating systems.

I'm particularly interested in regards to explicit linking, but I'd also like to know for implicit linking. I presume the answers for both will also be identical.

This is the best explanation I've found so far concerning Windows:

"The system maintains a per-process reference count on all loaded modules. Calling LoadLibrary increments the reference count. Calling the FreeLibrary or FreeLibraryAndExitThread function decrements the reference count. The system unloads a module when its reference count reaches zero or when the process terminates (regardless of the reference count)." - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

But it leaves some questions.

1.) Do unrelated processes load the same DLL redundantly (that is, the DLL exists more than once in memory) instead of using reference counting? ( IE, into each process's own "address space" as I think I understand it )

if the DLL is unloaded as soon as a process is terminated, that leads me to believe the other processes using exact same DLL will have a redundantly loaded  into memory, otherwise the system should not be allowed to ignore the reference count.

2.) if that is true, then what's the point of reference counting DLLs when you load them multiple times in the same process? What would be the point of loading the same DLL twice into the same process? The only feasible reason I can come up with is that if an EXE references two DLLs, and one of the DLLs references the other, there will be at least two LoadLibrar() and two FreeLibrary() calls for the same library.

I know it seems like I'm answering my own questions here, but I'm just postulating. I'd like to know for sure.

Comment: Make sure you understand virtual memory and paging. The actual addresses that processes see may be different no matter whether a separate copy of the library is loaded or not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The shared library or DLL will be loaded once for the code part, and multiple times for any writeable data parts [possibly via "copy-on-write", so if you have a large chunk of memory which is mostly read, but some small parts being written, all the DLL's can use the same pieces as long as they haven't been changed from the original value].

It is POSSIBLE that a DLL will be loaded more than once, however. When a DLL is loaded, it is loaded a base-address, which is where the code starts. If we have some process, which is using, say, two DLL's that, because of their previous loading, use the same base-address [because the other processes using this doesn't use both], then one of the DLL's will have to be loaded again at a different base-address. For most DLL's this is rather unusual. But it can happen.

The point of referencecounting every load is that it allows the system to know when it is safe to unload the module (when the referencecount is zero). If we have two distinct parts of the system, both wanting to use the same DLL, and they both load that DLL, you don't really want to cause the system to crash when the first part of the system closes the DLL. But we also don't want the DLL to stay in memory when the second part of the system has closed the DLL, because that would be a waste of memory. [Imagine that this application is a process that runs on a server, and new DLL's are downloaded every week from a server, so each week, the "latest" DLL (which has a different name) is loaded. After a few months, you'd have the entire memory full of this applications "old, unused" DLL's]. There are of course also scenarios such as what you describe, where a DLL loads another DLL using the `LoadLibrary` call, and the main executable loads the very same DLL. Again, you do need two `FreeLibrary` calls to close it.

Comment: I'm not understanding what you mean about "writable data parts" or "copy-on-write". I understand reference counting, the thing that threw me off there was the part of the link that said "The system unloads a module when its reference count reaches zero or when the process terminates **(regardless of the reference count)**."

Comment: Right, so there is a reference count PER PROCESS and another reference count of how many processes that use a particular DLL. If the process terminates (calls `exit` or crashes in some way), then the per process reference count is not used to determine the data. 

The writeable data parts - global variables in the DLL would have to be "per process", or it would potentially be pretty dangerous leakage between processes. Look up in google "copy-on-write", it will explain much better than I can in a post here.

Comment: "that, because of their previous loading, use the same base-address"
@MatsPetersson I am a bit confused by this. The OS is using physical addresses isn't it? And the OS can give different virtual addresses for the two DLLs if a process uses both, then why would they ever be the same?

Comment: If a DLL is loaded twice, it needs to be (at least partly) loaded into differnet physical locations, or have the same virtual address. There is likely to be some absolute addresses involved in the code, such as pointers to data or functions, that are stored somewhere, which means the virtual address has to be the same for all users of a physical loading of a DLL. And the OS doesn't generally "use" physical address. It assigns a virtual address to a physical memory region, but that's about the only time physical address is used.